# How to make a call using Skype API for mandriva?

Tags: skype, mandriva

I want to call and send message using Skype API for Mandriva 2011? I've tried skype4Py in Ubuntu and it works. Skype4Py is the only Skype-wrapper I've seen for Linux. Does anyone know how to make a call and send message for Mandriva 2011?

Answer (score 0):

To run skype API in mandriva using Skype4Py, go to installer /Skype4Py/api/posix.py and change

```
def SkypeAPI(opts):
trans = opts.pop('Transport', 'dbus')
```

to

```
def SkypeAPI(opts):
trans = opts.pop('Transport', 'x11')
```

then save and build and install again your setup.py. And run again your code to (call..etc) to skype using skype4py.